# Android equivalent to LockInfo

Tags: applications, lock-screens, ios

I am looking for an alternative to my jailbroken iPhone lockscreen, I currently use **LockInfo**

http://www.lockinfo.net/

[image]

I have googled and the only alternative I have seen is

**WidgetLocker**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker

WidgetLocker doesn't seem to provide the one touch (power button) access to reading my full my SMS, Email, Calendar that LockInfo currently does.

LockInfo also allows me to respond to these notifications straight from the lockscreen without having to enter my PIN.

Is there anything else on the market? Free or Paid.

I just ordered a Nexus 5 with 4.4 kitkat.

Comment: I have my configured here, http://i203.photobucket.com/albums/aa118/P90Puma/13AA68D1-BF47-434F-90CE-A6325BB004B0-12395-000004E8C20775BA_zps3eaeb72b.jpg you can see that I don't even have a slider getting in the way of the relevant information. The information appears and shows the screen when it is new, or I can press the power button and have it show up. No swiping needed.